# Apache Camel option in spring boot starter grey out

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I tried to create a project using spring boot with apche camel. But the Option to select it in eclipse is disabbled.
in the initalizr website also I am not able to select.
Can anyone help me on this

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot 2, then Camel is not yet compatible with SB2. Use Spring Boot 1 instead. Apache Camel 2.22 will work with Spring Boot 2 which is scheduled for release in June/July 2018.

Comment: Seems now its supported in latest spring initializr version

Comment: Yeah Apache Camel 2.23.0 onwards support Spring Boot 2.1. If you need to use older Camel version then you can use Spring Boot 2.0.x